# How can you effectively version control application parameters stored in a database?

Tags: postgresql, svn, configuration, parameters

We have a highly customisable application that is tailored to the needs of several clients using parameters stored in a PostgreSQL database.

For example, here is an example structure of the parameter table.

```
CREATE TABLE parameters
(
    client_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    environment_key VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    param_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    param_value TEXT
);
```

Example entries in this table might look like:

```
CLIENT_A    PRODUCTION    REMOTE_SERVER    "12.34.56.78"
CLIENT_B    PRODUCTION    REMOTE_SERVER    "78.56.34.12"
CLIENT_B    STAGING       REMOTE_SERVER    "127.0.0.1"
```

Each developer has a subversion working copy checkout out on their local computer AND a copy of the database. It's not a problem when a developer changes some code, as the SVN version control takes care of the details (e.g., merging files during an update, making sure the build/staging machine has the latest copy, etc). However, **we run into problems when someone modifies the parameters in the database, because the records are NOT version controlled**. This causes, e.g., one developer's updated parameters to overwrite another's, missing parameters on the build/staging machine, etc.

**QUESTION: What is the most effective way to solve the above issue?**

I can think of several options - you might have other alternatives.

1. Don't store parameters in the database. Store them in some kind of version controlled file (e.g., XML, JSON, TXT, etc).
2. Create a script or C-plugin for PostgreSQL to dump the contents of each record to the working copy.

Comment: I use tags like so: `[PREFIX_IDENTIFIER]` where prefix is a unique prefix for the client/job/server/etc and identifier is for perhaps version, ipaddress, url, etc. I've got a bash script setup that pulls from git/hg and does a find and replace. Not ideal but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably simplest to put the table under version control, and to edit your makefiles a little to make sure the database is up-to-date.

You can dump a single table to disk with [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html). Command-line options let you dump only the schema, only the data, or both. This command line dumps the data from my chemical_elements table to stdout.

```
$ pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -t chemical_elements --data-only sandbox
```

Developers will probably update the database itself. You can write the output of pg_dump to a temporary file, and use the exit status of `diff` or `cmp` to determine whether the controlled version and the current data are different.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (somehow alternative to Mike's way) is to add versioning to **all database changes** and it can be done rather easy and transparent with [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) on top of code-SCM and PostgreSQL

For end-users (developers) it means appearing one additional file (Liquibase changelog) in ordinary SVN commits and updating local database over Liquibase update only

Answer (score 0):

Keep the definitive version of your parameter data in version control:

```
begin;
delete from parameters;
insert into parameters values ('CLIENT_A', 'PRODUCTION', 'REMOTE_SERVER', '12.34.56.78');
insert into parameters values ('CLIENT_B', 'PRODUCTION', 'REMOTE_SERVER', '78.56.34.12');
insert into parameters values ('CLIENT_B', 'STAGING', 'REMOTE_SERVER', '127.0.0.1');
commit;
```

Use post-commit hooks in subversion to apply the script every time it gets updated.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Post-commit hook for applying parameter changes to db

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
DB=mydb
PARAM_SCRIPT="$REPOS/sql/parameters.sql"

psql "$DB" < "$PARAM_SCRIPT"
```

Comment: Hooks update server-side DB (which can not exist at all), developers have **local** databases. You MISS

Comment: Hmm, good point. The hook doesn't do much good here. Still, the approach could work using TortoiseSVN client-side hooks on Windows or a wrapper-script around svn on Linux. The other two answers require something similar as well.

Comment: Now that I think about it, all three answers are moving the source-of-truth for this data into a version-controlled text file. We have just provided three different mechanisms for doing this.